# How to maintain aspect ratio of an Image inside an ImageView Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a LinearLayout in xml file and i created an ImageView in the java code. I had to create ImageView in java code instead of xml because I need to alternate an ImageView with a TextView in the same LinearLayout.

This is my LinearLayout in my xml file:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
```

And this is part of my java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {    

        public ImageView questionImage;

           @Override
           protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
               super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
               setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

               LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLay);
               questionImage = new ImageView(this);
               LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new 
                       LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
                       LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
               layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
               questionImage.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
               ((LinearLayout) ll).addView(questionImage);

               // imageview.setScaleType doesn't work
               questionImage.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
               questionImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.imageA);
          }
}
```

The result is that i can see the imageA fit in all my LyinearLayout but without keeping its aspect ratio.
The LinearLayout has been set with a MATCH_PARENT width and a height of 0dp due to its weight of 5 (i have others TextViews and Buttons displayed in the same activity).

What i would like to do is to display imageA in the center of my LinearLayout keeping its aspect ratio at maximum possible size(e.g. imageA = 250p x 250p, LinearLayout = 400p x 600p  -> imageA resize to 400p x 400p and centered in the middle; e.g imageA = 250p x 250p, LinearLayout = 100p x 180p  -> imageA resize to 100p x 100p and centered in the middle).

Why setScaleType doesn't work? Sholud i do in a different way? Could you please help me with some example?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

I resolved it by using `questionImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.imageA);`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the aspect ratio of your image, SET adjustViewBounds property to true of your ImageView.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the property `adjustViewBounds` of the `ImageView` to true. Also, make sure that you set it as an `src` and not as `background` because setting it as `background` will make it scale and distort it.

[`setAdjustViewBounds`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setAdjustViewBounds(boolean))
And in case of setting the `src` programmatically, you can use [`setImageDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable))

Comment: I know about adjustViewBounds but how to use it in java code? I don't have ImageView in xml, i created it in java

Comment: @Ramal edited my answer

Comment: I don't think I understand which one should i use and how to implement to code. Colud you please show to me?